# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedBuffer$class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am newbie in Spark and Scala and trying the hands-on in Cloudera Quick VM 5.8 in intelliJ community edition.

Can someone please help me to rectify the issues?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RGiE.jpg)

[sbt File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMIrc.jpg)

Comment: Please let me know, if needs more information

Comment: Did you install Scala plugin and set up Scala SDK in IDEA?

Comment: For future: copy and paste code, don't screenshot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_2.10` in the Spark dependency means it works with Scala 2.10, not 2.12. As you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark), there is no `spark-core_2.12`, so use `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` and `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"`. Read more at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your clue helped me.